# If an electronic device specifies an operating RANGE between 6~15 volt with 210mA current, can you use a 9 volt battery to power it?

Tags: batteries, current

I have a FrSKY QX7 digital telemetry radio system (radio transmitter) and on its' specification it says

> Operating Voltage Range: 6~15V (2S, 3S Lips are acceptable)
> Operating Current: 210mA maximum (both RF module and backlit are on)

The thing didn't ship with a battery and I'm just trying to use it for a drone simulator- so if this doesn't work, i have to wait for a battery to get here and that's not fun.

I have a 9v battery, cables, and the battery that will eventually plug into this has a 2 prong connector into the circuit board.

So if i take a 9 volt battery, add wires to it, connect those two wires to the two prongs right there... based on the above stated operating voltage range, will it... work without damaging the unit?

It's a temporary hack, I just don't know enough about electronics to determine how bad of an idea it is. Thoughts? Ideas? Other solutions? Resources that dumb people like me can understand?

[image: connection]

Comment: At best it would work briefly.  Given you seem to be describing a stationary application ("simulator") you should probably find a mains power supply, or even better simulate this device rather than actually using it.

Comment: would you happen to be able to suggest what the google search term would be that i would need to find it? no obligation; no product suggestion necessary- i just don't know the terms or proper nouns i need to google it effectively

Answer (score 0):

If you connect it with the right polarity it wont damage the unit but it wont last more than some minutes and this depends also on the brand of the battery and its status. Since as it is shown in the following image for a given brand of batteries the voltage will rapidly drop for a current exceeding 50mA:

[image]